# how to save the data and the rows in a table with localStorage in html

Tags: javascript, html

What i want to save the rows with the data of this code, i know u can use `localStorage` but i can't figure out how to do it.do i need to add another button to save  the data or can i make it to save when i click "save" button or automatically.

this code has some bugs, like if u try to add the same pic twice it won't work.
it has to be a bit cleaned of but i will fix them later

```js
var r = 1;
var nrr = 1;
var img = 0;
var y;
var nr;
var z;
var i;
var image;
var imgUrl;
var x = document.getElementById("myTable").insertRow(r);
function fileChange(event) {
    imgUrl = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
}
var loadFile = function (event) {
    image = document.getElementById(di);
    image.src = imgUrl;
}
function insRow(id) {
    //if (imgUrl !== undefined && document.getElementById("Kodi").value !== "" && document.getElementById("Kodi").value !== "") {
    r += 1;
    x = document.getElementById(id).insertRow(r);
    nr = x.insertCell(0);
    y = x.insertCell(1);
    z = x.insertCell(2);
    i = x.insertCell(3);
    y.width = 200;
    z.width = 200;
    i.width = 100;
    nr.width = 50;
    z.height = 240;
    i.height = 240;
    nr.height = 240;
    nr.style = "text-align : center;font-size : 20px;";
    z.class = "z";
    i.class = "i";
    nrr += 1;
    nr.innerHTML = nrr - 1;
    y.append = "img";
    x.id = "r" + nrr;
    var di = "y" + nrr;
    y.innerHTML = "<img id=y1 src=''>";
    z.innerHTML = "<p id='zp'></p>"
    i.innerHTML = "<p id='ip'></p>"
    document.getElementById("y1").id = di;
    document.getElementById(di).src = imgUrl;
    document.getElementById(di).class = "yy";
    imgUrl = undefined;
    document.getElementById(di).title = "";
    document.getElementById("zp").innerHTML = document.getElementById("Kodi").value;
    document.getElementById("ip").innerHTML = document.getElementById("sh").value;
    document.getElementById("sh").value = "";
    document.getElementById("Kodi").value = "";
    // }
}
function delRow() {
    if (r != 0) {
        document.getElementById("myTable").deleteRow(-1);
        r -= 1;
        nrr -= 1;
    }
}
function save() {
    document.getElementById('y1').src = imgUrl;
}
```

```css
.file {
    height: 100px;
}

p {
    text-align: top-left;
    padding-left: 10px;
    font-size: 25px;
}

.kodii {
    width: 185px;
}

.shh {
    width: 90px;
}

.delete {
    position: absolute;
    left: 550px;
}

#myTable {
    width: 523px;
    height: 60px;
}

img {
    max-height: 300px;
    max-width: 200px;
}

.save {
    position: absolute;
    left: 500px;
}


div {
    width: 700px;
    height: 1000px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<input type="file" accept="image/*" name="image" style="color:transparent; width:90px;" title=""
    onchange="fileChange(event)"><label for="price">Kodi:</label>
<input type="label" maxlength="25" id="Kodi" value=""
    onchange="if (this.value == '') {border-color: red;}else{border-color : green};" class="kodii" name="price">
<label for="desc">Shtesë:</label>
<input type="text" maxlength="12" id="sh" class="shh" value="" name="desc">
<button type="button" class="save" onclick="insRow('myTable'); loadFile(event)">Save</button>
<input type="button" class="delete" onclick="delRow('myTable')" value="Delete row"></br></br></br></br></br></br>
<div>
    <table border="1" class="tablee" style="height: 20px;" id="myTable">
        <th width="50px">Nr</th>
        <th width="200px" border="2">Image</th>
        <th width="200px">Kodi</th>
        <th width="100px">Shtesë</th></br>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: You want to save the data of the table "myTable" to the localStorage?

Comment: yes, but if i create for ex. 2 rows with img and text i want the to be saved.

Comment: So, you want to save the data of "#myTable" and you also want that data to be updated automatically when you add some other stuff to the table?

Comment: i want the data to be saved when ever i want, if its posible to be automatically saved  if not then with a button.

Comment: Well, you can obtain the table's data in form of an `HTMLCollection`, then iterate over those elements and extract their data, the call the `localStorage.set` method using the key and the value you want to store.

Comment: Also, try to reduce the code to the bare minimum needed to understand the problem, and also try to improve your code redeability. For example, avoid polluting the global scope and try to use better namings for variables, if you can't come up with good names (naming can be pretty difficult!) try to use some comments, so others can understand your code faster.

If your problem is just that you don't know how to save data from a table to localStorage, you can just elaborate a reduced version of the code exposing the central part of the problem :)

Comment: ok, i tried to reduce the code but pretty much all the code is for the table so i didnt know what to not show

Comment: Can you visit this link and let me know if this is what you are looking for. https://codepen.io/dipankarmaikap/pen/abZNwgg

Comment: YES, thank you so much